# two diff style and effect of the "javascript:window.history.go(-1);return false;"

Tags: javascript, html

I write the html by MyEclipse10.7 and test it in Chrome.
I want to relize the function of "back to the previous page" by using the
`javascript:window.history.go(-1);return false;`,but it don't work.
In trying to solve this problem, I found a strange problem，like the two line code as follow:

```
<a href="url" οnclick="javascript:window.history.go(-1);return false;">返回上一个页面</a>

<a href="url" onclick="javascript:window.history.go(-1);return false;">javascript:window.history.go(-1);return
false;</a>
```

When I hover on the οnclick on the line one ,the IDE will show:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Undefined attribute name 
     (οnclick).
    - Undefined attribute name 
     (οnclick).
```

but when I do the same thing at line two ,it show:

```
Attribute : onclick
Data Type : EVENT
```

So,just like the IDE prompt,the line one don't work,and the line two word.
I wonder why?

Comment: What? You haven't asked a question. Please edit your post to ask a question.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I sent it out before I finished it. I just reedited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example has an "O" that is actually "GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON", written in UTF-8 as `0xCE 0xBF`. The second example you provided is actually ASCII O. Change the `o` in the `onclick` in your first example from UTF-8 "GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON" to ASCII O.

Here's a link to info about that specific character:

[https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=ο](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%CE%BF)

And here's a link to info about the ASCII o:

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=o

Good luck! Stuff like this can be really annoying in programming.

Comment: I kind of get it，the also show different where the Code in my question area. But I also want to know what caused it ?My workspace encoding is "utf-8"，and HTML charset also is "utf-8",Is that what happens when I copy code?

Comment: I see. Thank you.